# How to disappear uiview by a button click

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

I have created a unbutton programatically and made an action

```
{
UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 44); 
    [myButton1 setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton1];
}
```

and in IBAction i have a UIView as subview like this

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 50);
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];
}
```

What i now want is subview have to disappear when the user second time press myButton1. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do some correction in our code -**

```
**Action like this -** 

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
 {
   UIView *myView;
   if([self.view viewWithTag:56])
   {
    [[self.view viewWithTag:56] removeFromSuperview];
  }
  else
  {
   CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 50);
   myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
   myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  [myView setTag:56];
  [self.view addSubview:myView];
  [myView release];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `[view removeFromSuperView]` method to remove a view.

Comment: but when i use this subview is not showing at all. i want subview have to display when button is clicked first. when user again pressed the button subview have to disappear

Answer (score 1):

Change your `buttonClicked:` method to this.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
UIView *myView;
if(myView=[self.view viewWithTag:1234])
{
    [myView removeFromSuperview];
}
else {
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 50);
    myView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    [myView setTag:1234];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];
}
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

EDIT: It doesn't read well if you use `IBAction`  and not use the Interface Builder.

Comment: @jason try the edit. What is happening when you do this? Is it going in the method an the view is correctly added? Log everthing to see the flow.

Comment: working reversely now! during first click view not appearing. by second click it appearing.